# JsonArray from JsonArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, json-api

Want to extract data from this link -
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=16

This is my code to extract title and authors but i can get title but not authors.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(bookJSON);  
JSONArray bookArray = root.getJSONArray("items");
String autho = " ";

for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

    String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
    Log.i("booktitle",title);

    JSONArray auth = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
    for (int j = 0; j > auth.length(); j++) {
        autho = auth.getString(j);
        Log.i("authorname",autho);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray auth = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
int len = auth.length();
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    autho = auth.get(j).toString();
    Log.i("authorname",autho);
}
```

You need to get every index element of `JSONArray` and then convert it to `String`.

Comment: thanks  @Devendra but the bracket  it appear on screen with name of author  like this [Greg nudelman] i want to delete bracket  to no show with author name

Comment: Done. I have updated the code. Kindly have a look at it @mohammedragabmohammedborik